# Shopify Admin API, graphQL, create draft order - add products

Tags: graphql, shopify

This is my fist time creating an order. From what I understand you need to create a draft order - add products, price, email, notes etc. I am just creating a test query now to see how it works and it tells me "Add at least 1 product". I am trying to add a product, but I dont know how. I have been messing around and reading and cant figure it out.

This is my query:

```
mutation draftOrderCreate {
  draftOrderCreate(input: {email: "123abc@hotmail.com"}) {
    draftOrder {
      id
      order {
        id
      }

      status

    }
    
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone can give me an example on how to add products to this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an draft order like so:

```
mutation draftOrderCreate($items: DraftOrderInput!) {
  draftOrderCreate(input: $items) {
    draftOrder {
      id
      order {
        id
      }
      status
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

query variables:

```
{
    "items": {
        "email": "123abc@hotmail.com",
        "lineItems": [
            {
                "variantId": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/32231002996788",
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

Or if you don't want to use query variables you can pass the whole object as the input:

```
mutation draftOrderCreate {
  draftOrderCreate(input: {email: "123abc@hotmail.com", lineItems: [{variantId: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/32231002996788", quantity: 1}]}) {
    draftOrder {
      id
      order {
        id
      }
      status
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to reach out to you for a bit. I have a shopify-chat room I'd love to connect with you on.

Comment: I actually figured out how to do it last night. I bascially did your second example. One thing more thing if anyone knows. Can you add the total taxes with this order or how does that work?

Comment: When you pass in the email like that will it always create a new customer? The mutation accepts a customer ID too so I'm wondering if in order to create an order we need to a) query for customer b) create customer if doesn't exist c) create draft order d) mark order not as draft.